# Autoboxing performance

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, autoboxing

Why groups `j=k*l` and `m=n*o` have different performance, while first 3 groups have the same ?

```
int a = 42;
int b = 42;
int c = 42;

Integer d = 42;
int e = 42;
int f = 42;

int g = 42;
Integer h = 42;
int i = 42;

int j = 42;
int k = 42;
Integer l = 42;

Integer m = 42;
Integer n = 42;
Integer o = 42;

for(int z = 0; z < 1000000000; z++){
    // c = a*b; // 630 ms
    // f = d*e; // 630 ms
    // i = g*h; // 630 ms
    // l = j*k; // 6000 ms
    // o = m*n; // 6400 ms
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a loop which doesn't do anything useful.  As such the JIT can take some time to detect this and eliminate the loop.  In the first four examples, the code is taking an average of a fraction of a clock cycle.  This is a strong hint that the loop has been optimised away and you are actually measuring how long it takes to detect and replace the loop with nothing,

In the later examples, the loop is not optimised away because there is something about the loop which the JIT doesn't eliminate.  I suspected it was the object allocation for the `Integer` but `-verbosegc` showed that no objects were being created.

On my machine the loop take about 1.9 ns or about 6 clock cycles which is pretty quick so I am not sure what is left which takes that much time..

Comment: I'm just wondering about [this](http://pastebin.com/hVsm3CqW) modification, does it still eliminate the loop? (or, similarly, I would like to see the time results of an example where the loop isn't eliminated) (results obtained with Java 1.6.0_37)

Answer (score 4):

Creating a new object in a cycle always has a cost. In the last two examples you created new Integer objects in the cycle what has high performance cost.
Primitives are stored in stack, objects are in heap. Putting something into stack is cheaper than into heap.

Comment: You should add, that `42*42 > 127`, so there will be a new object created each iteration. If he used `10*10`, precached objects would have been used.

Comment: If you run with `-verbosegc` on Java 7 update 10 it doesn't create any objects (or not enough to trigger a GC)

Answer (score 4):

Basically this is what happening inside JVM and thats causing performance issue.

```
c = a*b; // 630  ms -> No boxing and unboxing
f = d*e; // 630  ms -> Unboxing d
i = g*h; // 630  ms -> Unboxing h
l = j*k; // 6000 ms -> Creates a new Integer object L, and assign J * K to L
o = m*n; // 6400 ms -> Creates a new Integer object 0, unbox m and n for calculation and assign m * n to o
```

***In other words***

l = j*k; // 6000 ms is equivalent to below code

```
temp = j*k;
Integer l = new Integer(temp);
```

o = m*n; // 6400 ms is equivalent to below code

```
temp = j.intValue() * k.intValue();
Integer l = new Integer(temp);
```

Your last two statements will create around `1000000000` (loop count) unnecessary `Integer` object. Which will be obviously a performance slog.

Comment: So, if `f = d*e`  was not optimized, it would be more costly than  `c = a*b` ?

Comment: Its equivalent to f = d.intValue() * e. If you see the intValue() source code it will Just send you the value. So ideally there should not be any performance issue there.

Comment: But it has to unbox the value like in `o=m*n` which is more costly. I figured that first `3` groups are optimized, so they yield same result and `2` last groups are not, so there is performance difference due to unboxing.

Comment: Am not saying both are equal it will have o=m*n difference. But the difference is intValue() method. Which will not take much time for processing. Because it just returns a value and does no other processing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Integer autobox has a small [cache](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29)
2. Creating an object costs a litter time

check this: java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `l = j * k` needs to box an int to an Integer, whereas `c = a * b` doesn't need to. The VM could also optimize the loop, understanding that executing a single iteration would lead to the same result as executing 1 billion. Beware of simplistic micro-benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

```
m = n*o  ==> Integer = Integer * Integer
```

while:

```
l = j*k ==> Integer = int * int // Integer is an object so autoboxing costs some performance here.
```

Comment: The first one has to auto-box just as such as the second.

Comment: Guess the compile optimizes the 1st one that it doesnt use the wrapper but the underlying primptive datatye (int) as all variables of the same type (Integer), while the second has to work on two stages, once primptive (int * int) then autoboxing (int => Integer).

Comment: If you run with `-verbosegc` you can see that no wrappers are being created. ;)

Comment: The Integer is a wrapper object, doesnt it need to be created??

Comment: Not if it's optimised away e.g. because it's not used.

Comment: where isnt it created in the 1st one(m = n*o), or in the second one (l = j*k)

Comment: None of the examples end up creating objects once they have been optimised by the JIT.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an object has an overhead (or, from other comments, it appears that it might be that, when creating an object, the loop can't optimised away because nothing is being done inside it).

`int = int * int`

No objects involved.

`int = Integer * int` or `int = int * Integer`

The Integer's int member get multiplied with the int, and no objects need to be created.

`Integer = int * int`

An Integer object needs to be created from the result (slow).

`Integer = Integer * Integer`

The two Integer's int members get multiplied, but then an Integer object needs to be created from the result (slow).